# devextreme component's icon not showed from CDN

Tags: devexpress, cdn, devextreme

i linked the style from the cdn

but no one icon is showed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.5/css/dx.common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.5/css/dx.light.css" />

<button id="myButton">click here</button>

$("#myButton").dxButton({
      icon:'add'
});
```

do i need some other files to include?
i forgot something or i need something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me if there is nothing inside the button html element:

```html
<button id="myButton"></button>
```

To set the button text, configure it in the button configuration like this:

```js
$("#myButton").dxButton({
    icon: 'add',
    text: 'click here'
});
```

```js
$("#myButton").dxButton({
  icon: 'add',
  text: 'click here',
  type: 'default',
  onClick: (ev) => alert('clicked')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.5/css/dx.light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.5/css/dx.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.5/js/dx.all.js"></script>

<button id="myButton"></button>
```

Comment: `if there is nothing inside the button html element`, BOOM!!! perfect.